# How to subtract quantity from the equipment table when there's a new borrow transaction made?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, html-table

I'm a Laravel newbie and I recently started working on a equipment management system whereby the admin adds quantity stock one each equipment to the system and when admin let the user borrow the equipment it deducts the quantity that the user wants from the equipment stock table. My only challenge is how to make the system to subtract quantity that the borrower wants from the equipment stock table?

Here's my controller for the button "borrow"
So when I click the borrow button it will deducts the ('quantity_item') to the equipment stock table ('e_quantity')

```
public function borrow($id){
   $first = Reservation::where('id', $id)->first();

    $kl = $first->name;
    $mn = $first->Name_item;
    $st = $first->quantity_item; //this is the quantity that the borrower wants
    $op = $first->dt_item;
    $qr = $first->room_item;
    $first->delete();

   $second = new BorrowedItems();

    $second->bname = $kl;
    $second->bdate = $mn;
    $second->itemb = $op;
    $second->bquantity = $st;
    $second->broom = $qr;
    $second->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Item Borrowed Successfully!');
}
```

This is my Equipment Stock Table
[image]

This is my BorrowedItem Table
[image]
so when I click the borrow button the data from reservationtable will transfer here

This is my Reservation Table
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In your controller you not use Equipment Stock Table? Can you just update item from this table.. what item attribute joint in tables

Comment: Those in the header of the table is also the attribute name.

Comment: sorry, can you add to question table structure (just structure) for 3 tables: Equipment Stock Table, BorrowedItems and Reservation. I understand that they are different tables

Comment: I already edited my question. Already added the table structure. Hope you can help me.

Comment: i think before transfer reserved to borrowed need check available equipment (enough quantity). For this need get quantity from EquipmentStock and sum already borrowed items.. if result >= reservation quantity -> you can transfer.
With this approach you not need change equipmentStock Table and you can dinamically count available quantity (a more robust approach than dealing with a constantly changing quantity attribute)